# Thomas a doctor?

Tags: gospel-of-john, thomas-apostle

Is it possible that Thomas as described in the Gospel of John chapter 20 is a doctor?  The reason for this is because of verse 5.  Thomas demands to see the mark of the nails in his hands, and put his finger in the mark of the nails and his hand in his side.  If Thomas was a medical doctor it would explain his response in verse 28, "My Lord and My God" after examining wounds that he knows are not survivable?

I am trying to establish if there is any correlation between the named apostles in John chapter 21 and the pseudonyms used for the authors of the gospels.  For example, Eusibeus/Papias states that John Mark was the interpreter and scribe for Simon Peter, we know that the son of Zebedee (John) according to tradition wrote the Gospel of John, but what about the other two... Nathaniel aka Bartholemew appears to be a Jew which would fit with the author of Matthew but what about Thomas? Was he working with a follower of Paul aka Luke to form the Gospel of Luke?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but that isn't enough. In John 20:19, 20, Jesus appears to the disciples and shows them his wounds. When the disciples tell Thomas, he says he won't believe unless he sees this for himself. Since the disciples weren't present during the crucifixion, the disciples must have told Thomas about the wounds, which prompted Thomas to even mention them.

Nothing about Thomas being a doctor is given as the reason he wanted to see the wounds himself. When Jesus appears a week later, he tells Thomas to touch the wounds. I find this to be insufficient to support or establish the likelihood of Thomas being a doctor.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas was a twin.  But unlike the other two sets of brothers James and John or Peter and Andrew, where's Thomas' twin?

Thomas is not so much a doubter, as one who has suffered loss.  He wasn't there Sunday afternoon, while the other apostles had gathered.

Then said Thomas, which is called Didymus, unto his fellowdisciples, Let us also go, that we may die with him.
John 11:16

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_the_Apostle

So no, Thomas is not Luke.

Comment: The Gospel does not make a conclusive statement that Thoma  did touch the wounds of Jesus.  His exclamation " My Lord and My God  " on the sight of Jesus , and also on the sudden realization that the Lord had  'overheard' what he had spoken to the other disciples,  is enough to have us believe otherwise.

Comment: I'd agree Thomas did not touch the wounds.  His heart would soar on the realization of the resurrection.